# CSS effects are delayed in SPFx App customizer

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I'm trying to hide the SharePoint App Bar using SPFx app customizer but while loading the page app bar first loads then is hidden.

How can I make the app bar not to load at the first place? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make your application customizer load before sharepoint.

But if you want to hide App Bar, you don't need App Customizer or SPFx. There is a command to disable it (temporarily)

`Set-SPOTemporarilyDisableAppBar $true`